# I have a OneToMany relationship between A to B. But when I do getB() I don't get multiple rows

Tags: java, hibernate, collections

Class A

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "A")
    private Set<B> Bs = new HashSet<B>();
```

Class B

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "INT_C", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "SBC_C", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false) })
    private A a;
```

When I do `getB()` I only get one row, where as for a combination of `INT_C` and `SBC_C`, there are 3 rows present.

Please let me know what is wrong here.

```
    Rows in DB

    SBC_C  INT_C FILE_C      OUTPUT_FILE_NM 
     --------------------------------------------
    MYACCESS  CR   CRC        DataHub_DEVC.dat  
    MYACCESS  CR   CRG        DataHub_DEVG.dat  
    MYACCESS  CR   CRU        DataHub_DEVU.dat
```

B Entity Id:

```
@EmbeddedId
    private ObFileId id;
```

ObFileId Class:

```
@Embeddable
public class ObFileId implements IXDomain {

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return getICode().hashCode() + getSCode().hashCode();
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return ((obj instanceof ObFileId)
            && (getICode().equals(((ObFileId) obj)
    .getICode())) && (getSubscriberCode()
    .equals(((ObFileId) obj).getSCode())));
}
```

Comment: I made a mistake there

The code is :

Class A:

 @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "outboundInterface")
 private Set<B> Bs = new HashSet<B>();

Class B:
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumns({@JoinColumn(name = "INTF_C", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false),
 @JoinColumn(name = "SBCR_C", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false) })
 private A a;

When I do getB(), I should get 3 rows, since 3 rows are present in DB, but I only get one row back.

Comment: Edit your question instead of adding a comment. Code in comments are really difficult to read, while you can format it in question texts.

Comment: Did you override the `equals()` and `hashcode()` methods of `B` class? It's very important when inserting instances in a `Set`. If you overrided them, please add the code to your question. Add also the rows you have in the tables.

Comment: No.  What do I put in there.  Could you please give an example.

Comment: For the sbcr_c='MYACCESS' and intf_c='ACR' there are 3 file codes which it should return, currently it returns the first row value for output file name.

Comment: How did you map your B entity? What is the declared @Id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you plan to add objects in `Collections`, such as `Set`, you must override the `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods, so that the system can compare 2 instances and detect whether they are equals. In `Sets`, You cannot have duplicates, so when you add an instance and another one inside the `Set` is equal to that instance, the second instance won't be added to the `Set`.

An example of an `equals()` method with an `int` as `id`, which identify perfectly the instance (primary key):

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof B) {
        B b = (B)o;
        return b.id == this.id;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And a possible `hashCode()` method:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return new Integer(id).hashCode();
}
```

Try to learn more about these 2 methods, because they are really important in java programming, and particularly with JPA/Hibernate.

**EDIT:**

The embeddable class includes 2 fields, but it's not the primary key of your B table, because the 3 rows have the exact same values for these 2 fields. The 3 rows are considered equals and after the first insertion in the `Set`, the other 2 are not added.

Add to your embeddable class all the fields that compose the primary key of your B table, and modify your `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods to include the new fields (`FILE_C` field could be the unique missing field). Then the rows should be considered different and each one should be added to the `Set`.

Comment: I edited my answer with the information of embeddable class you added to your question.

Comment: can you please unlink this from this account.